# Capitalize only words with more than 2 characters on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How can I capitalize only words with more than a specific count of characters? Google Sheets formula PROPER capitalizes all the words without any exclusions. For example, I would like to omit the capitalization of an acronym such as "PC" or "RAM" that is contained within a string in a cell.

Answer (score 0):

### Capitalize All and exclude from a list

To be able to [`PROPER()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094133?hl=en)/Capitalize the input of words and exclude others: 
**Use this formula**, but first we need the excluded list "Acronyms excluded".

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(
 REGEXMATCH(TEXTJOIN("^_~",,UNIQUE($D$2:$D)), UPPER(A2:A))<>TRUE,PROPER(A2:A),A2:A))
```

[image]

### Capitalize only words more than 2 charachters long

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,
              IF(LEN(UPPER(A2:A))<=2,
                 UPPER(A2:A),PROPER(A2:A))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work fine for single word strings.

Answer (score 0):

I may have been overthinking this by a mile, but try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("",0,IF(LEFT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\b(RAM|[A-Za-z]{1,2})\b","|♣$1|"),"|"))="♣",SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\b(RAM|[A-Za-z]{1,2})\b","|♣$1|"),"|"),PROPER(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\b(RAM|[A-Za-z]{1,2})\b","|♣$1|"),"|")))),"♣",""))
```

The point here is that `\b(RAM|[A-Za-z]{1,2})\b` would capture any 1-2 character word made of word-characters between word-boundaries **or** `RAM`. Now you can add any exclusion into the alternation of the pattern through concatenating more `|`. The replacement includes a backreference to the capture group to encapsulate the substring between a delimiter to split on and a leading unique character. The `IF()` will then check whether or not any element from the resulting `SPLIT()` needs to be processed with `Proper()` or not.

Note: Word-boundaries like `\b` may not be safe when you'd have data like `hello-pc` and you'd want this to be processed with `PROPER()`. A small adjustment to the formula is then needed.

Comment: Hi, this seems to work thank you very much. I'm still trying to figure out how to add more exclusions, would you please let me know how to add more? For example, if I would like to exclude HDMI as well as RAM, how would the formula look like? Thanks again.

Comment: @eduunlimited, see where it is written `(RAM|...`? Make it `(HDMI|RAM|...`. If it worked, mark it as such with clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.